# about a review book on analysis

Tags: analysis, book-recommendation

i have finished all undergraduate math courses and i am trying to review basic analysis before i start the measure theory.

but i am not really into analysis so i want to review a minimal amount. i have studied marsden in university but i don't like its style( proofs are all at the end of each chaptet). introduction to real analysis by bartle looks nice since it seems to be concise, very kind, withou heavy topologies.

so will it suffice to study the bartle's book to prepare for the measure theory? i am just worried if it is too weak or easy for the preparation for the measure theory.

Comment: May the gods have mercy on your soul.

Comment: i don't want irrelevant comments to be here.

Comment: Isn't 'measure theory' non-constructive? If you're 'not really into analysis' how can you expect to appreciate it?

Comment: my very question was if the bartle's book is good enough for the preparation for the measure theory. i am not into analysis which means i do not like it very much. but i have to do it for the study of differential geometry which is essential in the study of algebraic geometry. what you like and what you have to do is often different.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_differential_geometry